# json django model with custom fields representation

Tags: json, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I want to json this model with custom representation to pass it in javascript. I used the follow code for this by iterating through QuerySet

```
messages = Messages.objects.all()
passed_messages = []
for singleMess in messages:
    passed_messages.append(get_message(singleMess))
response = json.dumps(passed_messages)

def get_message(message):
    return {
        'user': User.objects.get_by_natural_key(message.userid).username,
        'content': message.content,
        'hour': message.time.hour,
        'minute': message.time.minute,
        'id': message.id
    }
```

But this part looks ugly. Is there a way to replace it with something nicer. I could use the followings

```
__repr__ in models.py 
django.core.serializers 
django.forms.models.model_to_dict 
Messages.objects.all().values()
```

I just don't know how to come across.
For example

- **json.dumps** needs a pure Python list of dictionaries, but **__repr__** returns **QuerySet** which I don't know how to conrent.
- If I use **model_to_dict** or **serializers** or **list(messages.values())** I can't  join the User's field username instead of userid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added property to my model class

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

  @property
  def json(self):
    return {
    'user': User.objects.get_by_natural_key(self.userid).username,
    'content': self.content,
    'time': self.time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
    'id': self.id
    }
```

And used comprehensions:

```
import json
messages = Messages.objects.all()
json.dumps([message.json for message in messages])
```